# How to group list elements in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to group a List of elements.In this case I have some grammar notations and I want to grouped elements in same group.if there are some fruits in the list then all fruits are merge in one list.Like that there are no birds then then the Birds list come as empty.I try to use `append/3` with matching but its not work.

Grammar rules:

```
animals-->[cat]|[dog]|[cow].
birds-->[parrot],[peacock]|[penquin].
fruits-->[apple]|[orange]|[banana].
```

The goal will come

```
?- grouped([[apple],[dog],[cat],[banana],[cow],[car]],Animals,Birds,Fruits,Rest).
Animals=[dog,cat,cow],
Birds=[],
Fruits=[apple,banana],
Rest[car].
```

Comment: If you're using a DCG, then the query looks like, `phrase(grouped(Animals, Birds, Fruits, Rest), L)` where `L` is your input. So think in terms of writing your DCG predicates as, for example a base case: `grouped([], [], [], []) --> [].`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you require the input to be a list of individual single-element lists? Wouldn't it be more logical to have as input, `[apple, dog, cat, banana, cow, car]`?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, and are those grammar rules for creatures given as-is? Those rules won't let you "capture" specifically what creature you're consuming on the input. For example, you'd really need, `animals(X) --> [X], { member(X, [cat, dog, cow] }.` or something like that so that when you use `animals(X)` in your DCG, you'll be able to know what `X` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share some perplexity with other commenters about your representation. Also, I think this clause

```
birds-->[parrot],[peacock]|[penquin].
```

should instead be

```
birds-->[parrot]|[peacock]|[penquin].
```

given the *semantic*, but syntactically is interesting to handle the generality of DCG - that is, without assuming that each DCG clause matches only *one* literal, as in your example. Then, my solution

```
:- meta_predicate capture(//,+,-,-).

capture(NT, L0, Capture, R) :-
    phrase(NT, L0, L1),
    append(C0, L1, L0), % recover tokens matched by NT
    capture(NT, L1, C1, R),
    !, append(C0, C1, Capture).
capture(NT, [Skip|L0], Capture, [Skip|R]) :-
    !, capture(NT, L0, Capture, R).
capture(_, L, [], L).

grouped(L0,Animals,Birds,Fruits,Rest) :-
    capture(animals,L0,Animals,L1),
    capture(birds,L1,Birds,L2),
    capture(fruits,L2,Fruits,Rest).
```

yields

```
?- grouped([apple,dog,cat,banana,cow,car],Animals,Birds,Fruits,Rest).
Animals = [dog, cat, cow],
Birds = [],
Fruits = [apple, banana],
Rest = [car].
```

For an aesthetic viewpoint, `grouped/4` doesn't like me too much ... but it does its job

Comment: CapelliC, yes thanks for your answer.It is correct.If i have the List like `[[apple],[dog],[cat],[banana],[cow],[car]]` how to get the goal?

Comment: could be `grouped(G0,Animals,Birds,Fruits,Rest) :-flatten(G0,L0),...`

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this by first creating some kind of database:

```
animals(cat).
animals(dog).
animals(cow).

birds(parrot).
birds(peacock).
birds(penquin).

fruits(apple).
fruits(orange).
fruits(banana).
```

Next you create some kind of filter:

```
grouped([],[],[],[],[]).
grouped([[H]|T],[H|A],B,F,R) :-
    animals(H),
    !,
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
grouped([[H]|T],A,[H|B],F,R) :-
    birds(H),
    !,
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
grouped([[H]|T],A,B,[H|F],R) :-
    fruits(H),
    !,
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
grouped([[H]|T],A,B,F,[H|R]) :-
    !,
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
```

Note that this predicate only works in one way. You can change it to work multidirectional however by removing the cuts and altering the last clause:

```
grouped([],[],[],[],[]).
grouped([[H]|T],[H|A],B,F,R) :-
    animals(H),
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
grouped([[H]|T],A,[H|B],F,R) :-
    birds(H),
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
grouped([[H]|T],A,B,[H|F],R) :-
    fruits(H),
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
grouped([[H]|T],A,B,F,[H|R]) :-
    \+ animals(H),
    \+ birds(H),
    \+ fruits(H),
    grouped(T,A,B,F,R).
```

Now however there is a possibility that collisions will start to occur (a `parrot` is for instance both a `bird` and `animal`).

But in my opinion there are few things rather strange with the question:

- why use a list of lists? `[[apple],[dog],[cat],[banana],[cow],[car]]` instead of `[apple,dog,cat,banana,cow,car]`?
- The design of using parameters as filter input/output (categories) is rather weird. If you would define a new category, it would result in rewriting the entire predicate. There are definitely better ways to do this.